# QGIS export png with accurate hex color values

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion, png

I have a 32 bit TIFF raster layer in QGIS with one band of integer values between 49 and 72 with some no data values. I'd like to end up with an 8 bit PNG image with matching pixel values. I don't care what no data ends up as as long as it's consistent. I've tried using GDAL translate, something like:

`gdal_translate -ot Byte -scale 0 255 -of PNG "in.tiff" "out.png"`

but the values I get back in the png range from 38 to 59 instead. Same range, but offset -13. Any ideas why, or how to do this properly?

Edit:
If I specify `-scale 49 72 62 85`, accounting for the offset I'm seeing, the values are correct. So that works, but it would be great to know why it's shifting -13.

Comment: Use -scale with both source and target range. It is documented on the gdal_translate manual page.

Comment: So, `-scale 0 255 0 255`? I also tried that, with the same result. The documentation says that the second `0 255` is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually appears to be a color management issue on my end, so probably not appropriate for this forum. Without any scale specified, if I load the resultant png in a web browser the colors are correct. I have not yet mastered Photoshop's color management settings and am not able to get Photoshop to show the correct colors. GIMP, however, does just fine.