# QGIS use the exact defined color for text labels and get rid of unused color when exporting as png

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, labeling, export, color

When I export QGIS layer as PNG images, I notice that the edges of the text labels are not clean.  There's always a zig-zag effect on the edge. And this in turn introduces a lot of unused colors that are different from the defined ones.

I wonder is there a way to get rid of this and have **color-consistent** text labels when exporting as PNG? I assume this should be related to the resampling configuration. It might have been set to "Linear" by default, but I want it to be "Nearest Neighbor".

I know there's the Resampling configuration for symbols, but I did not find the corresponding configuration for text labels. This question is very related to another post [Exporting a raster map to PNG in QGIS keeping the exact legend colors](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373070/exporting-a-raster-map-to-png-in-qgis-keeping-the-exact-legend-colors), and they are dealing with symbols, while I'm dealing with text labels.

I have set the antialiasing to be False, but the same thing still persists.

```
settings = iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()
settings.setOutputSize(QSize(1000,1000))

settings.setFlag(QgsMapSettings.DrawLabeling, True) 
settings.setFlag(QgsMapSettings.Antialiasing, False)
settings.setFlag(QgsMapSettings.UseRenderingOptimization, False)
settings.setFlag(QgsMapSettings.UseAdvancedEffects, False)
```

[image]

Comment: See if you can turn off anti-aliasing

Comment: @IanTurton, Yes I have turned off anti-aliasing with "settings.setFlag(QgsMapSettings.Antialiasing, False)"

Comment: which version are you using? this seems to be an issue that was fixed last year - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36964

Comment: @IanTurton,  Thanks for the info! I'm using v3.10, I'll try v3.12 and later